# Magento productAddToCartForm.submit() location?

Tags: magento

can anyone tell me please where is the productAddToCartForm.submit() locate in magento?

Thanks
Raja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find things by searching over the codebase:

```
grep 'productAddToCartForm.submit(' app/ -rsn

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml on line 35
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml on line 36       
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/paypal/express/shortcut.phtml on line 55
```